# how to run bitcoind server on a ubuntu 13.04 server

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to host a bitcoind on my server so I can connect to it on my website, how do I install it, run it, update the conf file? this is on a server not a desktop

Comment: How familiar are you with Linux?  There is nothing special about installing and running bitcoind as an app.  I installed mine over ssh.

Comment: first time. i managed to install it now I just need to figure how to edit bitcoin.conf file. Any idea?

Comment: http://kb.iweb.com/entries/21186923-Editing-files-in-SSH-using-VI